# Haskell proper use show function

Tags: haskell, show

So I am doing this in GHCI

```
Prelude> show (5, 6)
```

will get me

```
Prelude> "(5,6)"
```

But I want to print out (5, 6) without the comma in between.  So I tried

```
Prelude> show (5 6)
```

and I expect to get

```
Prelude> (5 6)
```

But it fails me with:

```
No instance for (Num (a1 -> a0))
      arising from the literal `5'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num (a1 -> a0))
    In the expression: 5
    In the first argument of `show', namely `(5 4)'
    In the expression: show (5 4)
```

Comment: filter (notElem ",'") (show (5,' ', 6)) seems to do the trick, there should be a better way.

Comment: seems slightly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851275/how-to-create-instance-of-read-for-a-datatype-in-haskell/7852258#7852258

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`(5 6)` is not a valid Haskell expression: it's trying to applying `5` as a *function* to `6`. If you want to print two values without a comma in between, define a function for that:

```
showPair x y  =  "(" ++ show x ++ " " ++ show y ++ ")"
```

Then try `uncurry showPair (5, 6)` or just `showPair 5 6`.

Answer (score 2):

`show (5, 6)` works because `(5, 6)` is a pair of value. But `show (5 4)` doesn't work because `(5 4)` doesn't mean anyting in Haskell. ghci is trying to apply `5` to `4` as if `5` were a function.

Answer (score 2):

You also make a new type from (a,b) like this:

```
newtype Tuple a b = Tuple (a, b)
```

And derive it from Show like this:

```
instance (Show a, Show b) => Show (Tuple a b) where
  show (Tuple (a, b)) = "(" ++ show a ++ " " ++ show b ++ ")"
```

Then in GHC:

```
*Main> Tuple (1,2)
(1 2)
```

This method is cool, but now, functions that operate with (a,b) don't work with Tuple a b:

```
*Main> fst (1,2)
1
*Main> fst (Tuple (1,2))

<interactive>:1:6:
Couldn't match expected type `(a0, b0)'
            with actual type `Tuple a1 b1'
    In the return type of a call of `Tuple'
    In the first argument of `fst', namely `(Tuple (1, 2))'
    In the expression: fst (Tuple (1, 2))
```

So be sure what do you want to use: writing new type or a function `showPair`.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it so that the above showPair function now works.

```
showPair :: (Int,Int) -> String
showPair p = "(" ++ show (fst p) ++ " " ++ show (snd p) ++ ")"

*Main> showPair (1,2)
"(1 2)"
```

Answer (score 0):

My Haskell is a little rusty (and don't have Hugs on this system), but i think something like this will do it:

```
showPair :: (Int,Int) -> String
showPair p = "(" ++ show (fst p) ++ " " ++ show (snd p) ++ ")"
```