# How to create instance of Read for a datatype in haskell

Tags: haskell, typeclass

So I have a data type

```
data SomeType a =
    Type a |
    Mix (SomeType a) (SomeType a)
```

This my show instance for SomeType

```
instance (Show a) => Show (SomeType a) where
    show (Type a) = show a
    show (Mix a b) = "(" ++ show a ++ " " ++ show b ++ ")"
```

So

```
Mix (Type 5) (Type 4)
```

would give me

```
(5 4)
```

Now I want to have

```
read "(3 4)" :: SomeType Int
```

produce

```
(3 4)
```

or

```
read "(a b)" :: SomeType Char
```

produce

```
(a b)
```

I am lost at how to use the Read class.

Comment: btw, your example for `SomeType Char` is not what `show (Mix (Type 'a') (Type 'b'))` would have generated.

Comment: You can derive both - the Show and Read instance - with a `deriving (Show, Read)` after the type delcaration. While they won't produce your output and input, they are a standard way of showing (and sometimes reading) values, which is why you should use them instead of your own instances. If you want to show them in a different way, use a separate function and call it `render` or so.

Answer (score 13):

Here's an example based on the [documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Text-Read.html#t:Read) which should be able to parse everything that `show` renders (assuming the type has a compatible `Read` instance defined), that is `read . show` should be more or less the identity:

```
instance (Read a) => Read (SomeType a) where
    readsPrec d r = readMix r ++ readType r
      where
        readMix = readParen True $ \r -> do
            (v1, r'') <- readsPrec d r
            (v2, r')  <- readsPrec d r''
            return (Mix v1 v2, r')

        readType r = do
            (v, r') <- readsPrec d r
            return (Type v, r')
```

Thus,

```
> read "(3 4)" :: SomeType Int 
(3 4)
it :: SomeType Int
```

But note, that for `SomeType Char` the default `Show` instance of `Char` surrounds the character with single quotes:

```
> read "('a' ('b' 'c'))" :: SomeType Char
('a' ('b' 'c'))
it :: SomeType Char
```

hope this helps

Comment: @Qin `d` is the operator precedence (which I accidentally incremented -- I've edited this) of the enclosing parsing context and `r` is the current remaining string to be parsed.