# What is the correct way to write a rich Haskell "show" function?

Tags: haskell, printing, io, idioms

My understanding of the [correct implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7852258/656912) for Haskell's `Show` and `Read` is that `read.show` should be identity. If true, then either `read` needs to be able to do some pretty messy string parsing, or `show` has to provide fairly limited functionality (from a user experience point of view).

Is it the case that `read.show == id`, and if so what is the accepted Haskell practice — for function naming and invocation — for richer (string) representations of values?

Comment: `pprint` is usually pretty understandable as an alternatively to `show` that does pretty output.

Comment: My advice: do not use `read`: it fails with `error`. You can use things like `maybeRead` (or `reads` function), but I think that `attoparsec` library is better - it could produce cleaner messages. Not using `read` lifts the restriction.

Comment: @bheklilr: Can you say a bit more about how to implement and use `pprint`. For my purposes, the best "display" is something very much different from the underlying representation of the value, and needs a good bit of formatting to get there. (Reading that representation, btw, would make almost no sense, since no user would enter it.)

Comment: `pprint :: PPrintOptions -> MyType -> String` or just `pprint :: MyType -> String`.  I can't really provide any more tips without knowing what the structure is and how you want to display it, which would be a different question anyway.  You can also optionally swap out `String` for `Text` or `ByteString` depending on your needs.

Comment: @bheklilr: What typeclass does `MyType` implement for `pprint`, and how is `pprint` invoked — `print` has the advantage of being "automatic", in GHCi, Jupyter Notebooks, and through `print`? (Awkward naming too; `print` actually prints, bit `pprint` really does something more like `pshow`, right?)

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius There isn't any standard typeclass, if that's what you're asking.  I just came up with a function name and a type signature.  If you would prefer using `pshow` then that's fine by me, if you wanted a typeclass with it then `class PrettyShow a where pshow :: a -> String` and then `pprint :: PrettyShow a => a -> IO (); pprint = putStrLn . pshow`.

Comment: @Heimdell Beyond `maybeRead` (from the *utility-ht* package) there is also `readMaybe` in `Text.Read` (which is in *base* and is therefore more accessible).

Comment: The entire `Read` mechanism is a bit of a throwback, based on an interesting idea about parsing that later developed in other directions. Aside from the fact that `Read` instances are relatively hard to write, there's the bigger problem that they're not usually terribly useful.  `Show` is primarily useful for debugging and interactive development in GHCi. I've not yet seen a killer app for `Read`. It's typically much more useful to write, say, `attoparsec` and/or `parsec` parsers, instances of serialization classes, `FromJSON` instances, etc.

Comment: @dfeuer: That (from my beginner vantage) seems accurate. `Show` seems like a debugging tool and not much more. It's certainly not for end use. The  absence of a `PShow` typeclass [seems an omission](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32532617/656912).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, `show` is expected to produce a string following the Haskell syntax -- ideally, one should be able to cut & paste that into a Haskell file and have that work.

That being said, `read . show` is expected to be the identity. However, sometimes it is relaxed a bit, only requiring that

```
read (show x) == x
```

where `(==)` is the *equivalence* defined by the related `Eq` instance.
I believe the archetypal example for this is `Data.Set.Set`, which internally represents sets using balanced binary search trees (BST). Its `Show` instance produces strings of the form

```
fromList [1,2,3,4,6,7]
```

`read`ing back such a string likely produces a different BST, but one which is still `==` to the old one. From the user's point of view, there's no (observable) difference.

When printing a custom "opaque" type the same `fromSomeTransparentType value` string encoding can often be used.

Finally, I guess these `Show`-related "social contracts" are much more respected in *libraries* than in *applications*. This is because in applications one sometimes can reasonably assume that no one else - but the application itself - will ever use these instances. E.g., I think this is okay-ish for an application:

```
data Exp = Add Exp Exp | ...
instance Show Exp where
   show (Add e1 e2) = "(" ++ show e1 ++ ", " ++ show e2 ++ ")"
```

---

The "other" law `show . read == id` does not hold, in general. First, `read` is partial. Second, even disregarding partiality, the `read` method is allowed to be more lenient on its input, e.g. treating repeated whitespace as a single one, or neglecting redundant parentheses: (as AJFarmar suggests below)

```
show (read "Just (((6)))") = "Just 6"
```

Comment: I think you should clarify a bit by saying something like `show (read "Just (((6)))") = "Just 6"`, which is clearly not the identity, but nonetheless correct.

Comment: @AJFarmar I added a note, even if the OP asked about `read.show`, not `show.read`. Still, the latter can be interesting for comparison with the former.